# How do I create a sequence of rectangles in tikz with spectrum of color and shadowing?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to have a simple way in tikz to create a sequence of rectangles (such as below) where there is a base color that fades (becomes lighter) with each rectangle stacked lower. The rectangles should be specified just by width and height of each rectangle, there is no need for an absolute position for all of them, because they are all stacked (though I do need to choose where to put the stack).

Is there a way to do it in tikz without basically building it rectangle by rectangle with highly specified coordinates?

[image]

Here is an example image to generate in tikz:

only say the first rect on top would be very red (basecolor) and fading until the last rectangle at the bottom.

Comment: Where is your LaTeX-work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a macro `\rstack[<width>]{<height list>}{<color>}{<top label>}`. `<width>` is optional. Default is 3cm. `<height list>` should be a comma-separated list of heights of the rectangles, from back to front (which is the order they're drawn).

[image]

So `\rstack{1.5,5,4,2,1}{red}{$\mathbf{x}_k$}` produces the stack on the left and `\rstack[2cm]{4,3,1,2}{blue}{}` produces the right one.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newcommand{\rstack}[4][3cm]{\tikz[baseline]{
    \foreach \k[count=\n] in {#2}{\xdef\numrecs{\n}}
    \foreach \k[count=\n, evaluate=\n as \c using \n/\numrecs*100] in {#2}{
        \node[shift={(-\n/4,-\n/4)}, draw, thick, fill=#3!\c, drop shadow, inner sep=0, minimum height=\k cm, minimum width=#1, anchor=north east](r\n) at (0,0){};
    }
    \node at (r\numrecs){#4};
}}

\begin{document}

\rstack{1.5,5,4,2,1}{red}{$\mathbf{x}_k$}\qquad\rstack[2cm]{4,3,1,2}{blue}{}

\end{document}
```